# Building Yocto for i.MX8 in an external USB HDD

Tags: yocto, bitbake, hard-drive, imx6, imx8

I'm trying to build an image using bitbake for the i.MX8 board.
I'm following these instructions:

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/IMX_YOCTO_PROJECT_USERS_GUIDE.pdf

Since I do not have enough space in local HDD, I'm using an external USB HDD (I have other unrelated stuff stored in this HDD).

I have been successfull at executing the imx-setup-release.sh script in that document, with which I built a configuration for the imx8mm-lppddr4-evk machine using the fslc-wayland distro.

However, when I try a command, such as "bitbake core-image-minimal", I get several failed tasks. It seems that the common deminator is the fact that, for some reason, when the path to my build folder is passed (which is within the external HDD), it is considered an invalid argument.

I get messages such as this:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/media/home_dir/427AD2297AD2198D/imx-yocto-bsp/build_fslc_wayland_imx8mm_lpddr_evk/sstate-cache/95/51/sigtask.1jbsd4s4' -> '/media/home_dir/427AD2297AD2198D/imx-yocto-bsp/build_fslc_wayland_imx8mm_lpddr_evk/sstate-cache/95/51/sstate:core-image-minimal:imx8mm_lpddr4_evk-fslc-linux:1.0:r0:imx8mm_lpddr4_evk:3:955169ece771b852dc433575442e7ed805ac56cbcb1ebd3aa913a632da23a46b_clean.tgz.siginfo'.
```

It seems that bitbake is having trouble parsing the path to my HDD (that 427AD.../ folder).

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the file format on your external HDD? Is it ext3/ext4?

Comment: Make sure that the HDD is formated in a Linux format (ext4 recommended), also make sure that you have write permissions, and a hint: set a name or label to your driver so it be fixed, because if the drive name changes the build will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my HDD was not formatted with an ext4 format. Once I did that, those errors went away.